# Laravel's pretty var_dump(), dd(), not working anymore

Tags: laravel

For some reason laravel's `dd()` function decided to stop functioning. I have no idea how this happened. I tried `composer update` already but I'm not sure what else can be going on. The `debug` key is set to `true` in the config.

Where should I look to solve this problem? I'm using Laravel 4.2.16

NOTE:
`dd()` now simply functions as `var_dump()`, it doesn't prettify it anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. I loaded my vagrant machine with the wrong config and was running hhvm instead of regular php-fpm. Hence xdebug, which handles the pretty `dd()`, was not being loaded. I reloaded my box with the correct settings (without hhvm and hack) and everything started working again

Comment: how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Is dd the only Laravel helper function that doesn't work?  If not then check the contents of vendor/composer/autoload_files.php.  The laravel support helpers are loaded here.  If the other helper functions are fine you can check the contents of laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php to see what's going on - this is where the function is created.

Comment: I checked the dd function and it's the same as the source. I echoed something out so the function is not being overwritten. I also want to explicitly say that it does var_dump everything, it's just not pretty