# Laravel dd helper function returns error 500

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to `dd('string')` but it's returning error 500. My error_log is:

```
strpos(): Empty needle {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): strpos(): Empty needle at /vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/ContextProvider/SourceContextProvider.php:101)
```

Only `dd` and `dump` not working, not other helper functions. it was working properly on local but when I uploaded it to the server it won't anymore, I guess the problem is from `php-fpm` maybe as this stack [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734788/laravels-pretty-var-dump-dd-not-working-anymore) mentions.

How can I figure out where the problem is from?

Comment: last i checked, `string` is not a valid dd command, and indeed: ```$ dd string
dd: unrecognized operand ‘string’
Try 'dd --help' for more information.``` - see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html

Comment: @hanshenrik I think OP was refering to Laravels [dd helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-dd)

Comment: @kerbholz yeah - but then he shouldn't use the `dd`-tag, maybe try `laravel-dd` tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like a bug in [Symfony's VarDumper component](https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper/)
, in `/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/ContextProvider/SourceContextProvider.php` near line 101, replace

```
    if (null !== $this->projectDir) {
        $context['project_dir'] = $this->projectDir;
        if (0 === strpos($file, $this->projectDir)) {
            $context['file_relative'] = ltrim(substr($file, \strlen($this->projectDir)), \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        }
    }
```

with

```
    if (isset($this->projectDir) && is_string($this->projectDir) && strlen($this->projectDir) > 0) {
        $context['project_dir'] = $this->projectDir;
        if (0 === strpos($file, $this->projectDir)) {
            $context['file_relative'] = ltrim(substr($file, \strlen($this->projectDir)), \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        }
    }
```

that should fix it.

someone should also file a bugreport so it gets fixed upstream.